# Filter a list of pairs by their key in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a list of pairs that simulate a dictionary, like `[("key1",32);("key2",54);...]` and I need a function that can filter the list and return a new list, remove the pair that have duplicate keys.

Example: a list like `[("key",32);("key",78);("anotherKey",12)]` has to be filtered as `[("key",32);("anotherKey",12)]`.

I've achieved this using Hashtable, but I prefer a solution that use List instead. In the code below I can't find a way to substitute hashtable with a list, because in the `else` branch i don't know how to proper update the `seen` list.

```
let getKey (k,v) = k;;

(* Hashtable *)
let filter (list : (string * int list) : (string * int) list =
  let seen = Hashtbl.create (List.length list) in
  List.filter 
    (fun pair -> 
       let exists = not (Hashtbl.mem seen (getKey pair)) in
       Hashtbl.replace seen (getKey pair) (); 
       exists) 
    list
;;

(* List *)
let filter (list : (string * int) list) : (string * int) list = 
  let seen = [] in
  List.filter 
    (fun pair -> 
       let exists = List.mem (getKey pair) seen in 
       if exists then failwith("duplicate")
       else (* what to do here? *); 
       true) 
    list
;;
```

Comment: You need to make filter recursive and pass the updated seen to the next call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand what is the problem. As for me, the solution can be expressed quite clearly:

1. Take the head element of the list to deduplicate.
2. If it is not a member of the result list, add the head element to the result list
3. If it is a member already - skip it
4. Deduplicate (repeat 1-3) the tail

The implementation just follows the description:

```
let rec is_member key = function
  | [] -> false
  | (k, _)::tail ->
    if k = key then true
    else is_member key tail
;;

let dedup list =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | ((k, v) as hd)::tl ->
      if is_member k acc then aux acc tl
      else aux (hd::acc) tl
  in aux [] list
;;

utop # dedup [("key",32);("key",78);("anotherKey",12)];;
- : (string * int) list = [("key", 32); ("anotherKey", 12)]
```

Regarding the standard library (and List in particular) you cannot achieve your goal using `List.filter` - because this function doesn't accumulate the result but just iterates over list elements one by one. If you need an accumulated result you should use smth. like `fold_left` instead, for example:

```
let dedup_list list =
  List.fold_left (fun acc ((k, v) as el) -> if is_member k acc then acc else el::acc) [] list
  |> List.rev
;;

utop # dedup_list [("key",32);("key",78);("anotherKey",12)];;
- : (string * int) list = [("key", 32); ("anotherKey", 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lists unfortunately will result in your code having O(n^2) runtime complexity, since you have a loop within a loop... unless you do some more work.

You need either a better data structure or a better algorithm.

The better data structure would be a map. The `Map` module in OCaml uses a balanced binary tree internally, so lookups are O(log n) rather than O(n) with an association list.

```ml
# lst 
  |> List.fold_left 
       (fun m (k, v) -> 
          StrMap.update k (function None -> Some v | x -> x) m)
       StrMap.empty 
  |> StrMap.bindings;;
- : (string * int) list = [("anotherKey", 12); ("key", 32)]
```

Alternatively, we can use a map by reversing our list (linear time complexity) converting it to a sequence, then building a map from that sequence. The later duplicates will overwrite the earlier ones, but because we started by reversing the list, we'll end up with the earliest value for each key.

```ml
# lst 
  |> List.rev 
  |> List.to_seq 
  |> StrMap.of_seq 
  |> StrMap.bindings;;
- : (string * int) list = [("anotherKey", 12); ("key", 32)]
```

If you want to only use lists, you can do this, but it's much more efficient if we sort the list by the keys first.

```ml
# let sort_by f lst = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst in
  lst
  |> sort_by fst;;
- : (string * int) list = [("anotherKey", 12); ("key", 32); ("key", 78)]
```

If all entries with the same keys are grouped together, eliminating duplicates is quite straightforward and can be done as an O(n) operation.

```
# let[@tail_mod_cons] rec eliminate_dupes f = 
    function
    | ([] | [_]) as x -> x
    | x::(y::z) when f x = f y -> eliminate_dupes f @@ x :: z
    | x::(y::_ as tl) -> x :: eliminate_dupes f tl
  in
  let sort_by f lst = List.sort (fun a b -> compare (f a) (f b)) lst in
  lst
  |> sort_by fst
  |> eliminate_dupes fst;;
- : (string * int) list = [("anotherKey", 12); ("key", 32)]
```